# checking for availability for parking spots using laravel and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, overlap, overlapping, parking

I have a problem with MYSQL query to get the overlapping with reservations.

We are working at project to book a parking for cars, And we have a problem in searching for availability

if the user searches for a parking between two dates, we need to get the remaining available number of parking.

the problem here is not the overlapping dates and times

for example, we have 3 reservations, the 1st one from 1-3/8, the second is from 3-5/8 and the 3rd is from 5-7/8 and we have 5 available spots, and the user is looking for 1 - 7/8, the remaining available spots is 4, not 2. because each reservation starts after another one is done.

we tried several solutions, like checking every hour of search

but that’s not a good solution especially when searching for long times/dates

This is an image explain what is the problem

[image: Overlapping]

[image: OverLapping]

Thanks

Comment: Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) then read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You might also like to see my expatiation on RF's theme: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)